# Writing an XSD schema to validate any XML file as valid

Tags: eclipse, xsd, logback

I'm often getting the warning in Eclipse:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document: logback.xml

Because of Logback's configuration file "flexibility" no validation schema is possible.

Thus, as a way of getting around the issue altogether, is there an XSD available on the internet that validates any structurally valid XML file as being valid, so I can trick Eclipse into being silent about the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always disable the warning in eclipse. Go to Preferences-->XML-->XML FILES --> Validation and Select "ignore".

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
```

at the top of your *logback.xml* (right after the `<?xml...>`).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there is no such XSD, capable of matching any XML. You'll have to find an alternate way, such as, maybe, the one already suggested (disable validation).

I wouldn't probably do it, simply because you may have to flip back and forth when editing other XML files for which you want validation.

I would try instead to define a dummy XSD, which will define the root element of your logback configuration file as anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's a more direct way to handle Logback configuration specifically:

- Open Preferences->Validation. Click the "..." button for Settings next to XML Validator
- There should already be an Exclude Group for Eclipse internal files. Click "Exclude Group" and then the "Add Rule..." button.
- Select "Folder or file name".
- Enter `logback.xml` and finish.
- Repeat for `logback-test.xml` if you use a separate logging configuration for testing.

This will keep Eclipse from running XML validation on exactly these files but will keep validation active for the rest of your XML.